# Android osmbonuspack-4.7 and mapsforge

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapsforge

I tried to use MapsForge maps in my app (with osmdroid-4.2 and osmbonuspackv-4.7).
Apparently, osmbonuspack-4.7 supports now mapsforge source maps: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/OSMNavigator#Using_MapsForge_maps

I saw in the osmnavigator example code (https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMNavigator/src/com/osmnavigator/MapActivity.java) that I need to "import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.mapsforge.GenericMapView" but this is not available in osmbonuspack lib...
Anyone can help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

PS.

Answer (score 0):

Since osmdroid-5.2 the mapsforge support has moved from `osmbonuspack` to  the new `osmdroid-mapsforge` package. There is also an up to date demo app `osmdroid-forge-app` that demonstrates `osmdroid-android` + `osmdroid-mapsforge` to show offline map files. for details see https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid